# How to instantiate a Custom UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableViewCell and my cells contain a UIButton subclass (CoolButton).
I have picked the code of CoolButton from raywenderlich tutorial 
[available here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33330/core-graphics-tutorial-glossy-buttons)

In the IB I have created a subclass of the UITableViewCell and I have configured the class of my button to CoolButton and set the property type to Custom and configured the IBOutlet for the CoolButton to my UITableView subclass.

My problem is when cells are created, they get a UIButton instead of a CoolButton. As a consequence when I'm setting the properties of the CoolButton I get a crash with "unrecognized selector".

Why UIButton is instantiated instead of a CoolButton? How can I get my CoolButton in the table?

Thanks,

Séb.

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you are doing something like:

```
CoolButton *b = [UIButton ...]
```

You need to create it using the CoolButton class:

```
CoolButton *b = [CoolButton ....];
```

Or, if you used IB, that you created a UIButton but used an IBOutlet of CoolButton. You would need to make the actual class of the button you drag into IB CoolButton, which you can do by selecting the button and tapping (I think) the second to the left top tab in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using IB but as explained I made the actual class of the button to CoolButton and then drag it to my UITableViewCell subclass (it has created a property with the class CoolButton). Unfortunately it doesn't work, it still instantiate a UIButton instead of the CoolButton.

Comment: Ah, CoolButton may not implement "-initWithCoder", which is what gets used when an object comes from IB, so when IB calls that, it goes down to UIButton's. Add it to the class and you will now have a CoolButton. I used this class years ago and now I'm getting a vague memory tug that I had to do this. You can put any code that is run now in initWithFrame into a "setup" method and call that from both initWithFrame and initWithCoder. Add a NSLog to initWithCoder and if you don't see that message, you didn't get the class right in IB.

Comment: I found the issue and I'm feelling a little bit idiot...

The problem is the source file Common.m and CoolButton.m were not included in my Target Project (in Build Phases / Compile Sources). 
When I have imported these files in my project I have just drag&drop the sources files but I forgot to add them in "Build Phases / Compile Sources".

Now, it's working and I can use this "Cool Button" from the IB. I accept you answer because it's the right way to instantiate the Button.
Thanks